# Invalid resource property cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm attempting to use CloudFormation to automate some build deployments.  I'm right now trying to create a VPC with a public subnet, but I keep getting this error

```
A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Invalid template resource property 'PublicSubnet'
```

The portion I have in the template is as follows:

```
       "PublicSubnet" : {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
        "Properties": {
            "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Name": "public-1"
                },
                {
                    "VpcId": {
                        "Ref": "DemoVPC"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it may have been a spacing issue, which for some reason made it think that it was a resource property.  This is weird because it was JSON-validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for an [AWS::EC2::Subnet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html) is:

```json
{
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
   "Properties" : {
      "AvailabilityZone" : String,
      "CidrBlock" : String,
      "MapPublicIpOnLaunch" : Boolean,
      "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ],
      "VpcId" : { "Ref" : String }
   }
}
```

It seems like your VpcId is inside `Tags` when it shouldn't be. The [Tag Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html) has the following properties

```json
{
  "Key" : String,
  "Value" : String
}
```

Comment: I wanted the tag name to be "VpcId", it turns out I was using the "Tags" syntax incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This error message will also commonly appear if the JSON structure of your document is out of shape. It's easy to get confused with open- and closing brackets without good tooling.

Comment: Or even worse, bad YAML. I got this error when one of my function declarations was improperly tabbed. The error message certainly doesn't point one in the right direction, unless you deduce that the reason for the missing property is formatting

Answer (score 0):

For creating subnet resource, VpcId and CidrBlock are mandatory. Eventhough you can have VpcId as a tag itself, VpcId should be one of Properties. For more details, refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html, specifically those that says **Required**